# Bootstrap row-fluid 7 tiles in 3 row without spaces

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm having problems cancelling the spaces on my tiles. I need it to be 3 rows and 7 tiles without spaces.

```
<section class="the-team">
    <div class="container text-center">
        <div class="row-fluid">
             <img src="images/profiles/1.jpg">
             <img src="images/profiles/2.jpg">
             <img src="images/profiles/3.jpg">
             <img src="images/profiles/4.jpg">
             <img src="images/profiles/5.jpg">
             <img src="images/profiles/6.jpg">
             <img src="images/profiles/7.jpg">
             <img src="images/profiles/8.jpg">
             <img src="images/profiles/9.jpg">
             <img src="images/profiles/10.jpg">
             <img src="images/profiles/11.jpg">
             <img src="images/profiles/12.jpg">
             <img src="images/profiles/13.jpg">
             <img src="images/profiles/14.jpg">
             <img src="images/profiles/15.jpg">
             <img src="images/profiles/16.jpg">
             <img src="images/profiles/17.jpg">
             <img src="images/profiles/18.jpg">
             <img src="images/profiles/19.jpg">
             <img src="images/profiles/20.jpg">
             <img src="images/profiles/21.jpg">
        </div>
    </div><!--//container-->
</section>
```

[image]

How do I cancel the spaces between the tiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space is caused by the whitespace between the images.  In HTML any amount of whitespace between inline elements is treated as one space.

If you set a font-size of 0 on the div, the space will vanish.

```
.the-team .row-fluid {
    font-size:0;
}
```

This can also be fixed in the HTML by removing the spaces and returns between the images.

Another method is to put a small negative margin on the left side of the image, about .25em on all but the first image. this last choice is not very robust as the margin needed varies with the font and will overcompensate if the space is missing.

Comment: To fit all the 7 tiles per row i resized the images :) thank you so much! :)

Comment: Not really, I've just been burned by this monster in the past.  There are numerous cures, another is to make the images `display:block; float:left` since the space only applies to inline elements.  It's also a common problem with `<a..>`